# What exactly does the Timber library do?

Tags: android, timber-android

I heard about [Timber](https://github.com/JakeWharton/timber) and was reading github `README`, but it's quietly confusing me.

> Behavior is added through Tree instances. You can install an instance
>   by calling Timber.plant. Installation of Trees should be done as early
>   as possible. The onCreate of your application is the most logical
>   choice.

What behavior?

> This is a logger with a small, extensible API which provides utility
>   on top of Android's normal Log class.

What more does it provide on top of Android's Log?

> The DebugTree implementation will automatically figure out from which
>   class it's being called and use that class name as its tag. Since the
>   tags vary, it works really well when coupled with a log reader like
>   Pidcat.

What is DebugTree?

> There are no Tree implementations installed by default because every
>   time you log in production, a puppy dies.

Again, what is a tree implementation? What does it do? And how do I stop killing puppies?

> Two easy steps:
>
> Install any Tree instances you want in the onCreate of your
>   application class.
>
> Call Timber's static methods everywhere throughout your app.

Two easy steps for accomplishing what?

None of this has been explained in the Readme. It's pretty much a description for someone who already knows what it is :/

Comment: [This article](https://medium.com/mindorks/better-logging-in-android-using-timber-72e40cc2293d) answers all of your question at once.

Comment: It has quite confusing README. Still, I have many doubts about performance over Log.

Comment: There's a lesson here: poor documentation is a problem. `Timber` introduces concepts like "Trees" and "Planting", but it fails to explain that in its README: the 1 place you should go to learn what these mean. 

The fact that we need SO and a Medium article to understand its fundamental concepts is quite sad. Great library, poor communication.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Problem :-

We do not want to print logs in Signed application as we may sometimes log sensible information . Generally to overcome this developers tend to write if condition before writing log

Example:-

```
 if(BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
      Log.d(TAG,userName);
  }
```

so every time you want to print a log you need to write a if condition and a TAG which most times will be class name

Timber tackels these two problems

You just need to check condition once in application class and initialize `Timber.plant`

```
class MyApplication : Application() {

override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()

    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        Timber.plant(DebugTree())
     }
 }

}
```

remaining all places we can just write  `Timber.d("Message")` without any tag or if condition .

If you want a different tag then you can use

```
  Timber.tag("Tag").d("message");
```

**Edit :**

Also you can plant your own trees in Timber , and  do some cool stuff like Log only warnings and error in release , send warnings and error logs to server etc . eg

```
import timber.log.Timber;

public class ReleaseTree extends Timber.Tree {
  @Override 
  protected void log(int priority, String tag, String message, Throwable t) {

    if (priority == ERROR || priority == WARNING){
      //Send to server
    }

  }
}
```

You can plant different trees for different build flavours .

Check out this [article](https://itnext.io/timber-enhancing-your-logging-experience-330e8af97341) and have a listen to this [podcast](https://fragmentedpodcast.com/episodes/191/)

Comment: Where did you get the `ERROR` and `WARNING` priority codes? They are nowhere defined in the library. I need those to properly format my messages.